# How to use the post_title of custom post type as taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a few custom post types to define various types of content and one CPT to configure which fields should get rendered. The config CPT also defines a taxonomy so I can pick and choose with which config a CPT gets rendered.
The taxonomy term is defined by the `post_title` of its CPT.

Adding a term to the taxonomy is no problem hooking into the `save_post`-hook.
My problem is with changing the name of a taxonomy or deleting it. The expected behaviour is that when I change the `post_title` of my taxonomy that the name of the exixtig taxonomy term gets also changed. At this time there is just a new one added.
Same with deleting the CP which defines a taxonomy.

Is there a hook that actually only fires when a post gets updated and where I can get `$post_before` and `$post_after`?
If not, how can I reliably check if a post gets updated?
The `save_post`-hook gets fired when creating a post for the first time as well as when updating an  existing post which is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a hook that actually only fires when a post gets updated and where I can get $post_before and $post_after?

You're probably looking for the [`post_updated`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_updated/) hook.

#### Usage

```
add_action( 'post_updated', 'wpse_264720_post_updated', 10, 3 );
function wpse_264720_post_updated( $post_ID, $post_after, $post_before ) {

  //* Bail if this is an autosave
  if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
  }

  //* Bail if this is a post revision
  if( wp_is_post_revision( $post_ID ) ) {
    return;
  }

  //* Bail if not the correct post types
  if( ! in_array( $post_after->post_type, [ 'post-type-1', 'post-type-2' ] ) ) {
    return;
  }

  //* If you add/update/delete posts, remove action to avoid infinite loop
  remove_action( 'post_updated', 'wpse_264720_post_updated', 10 );

  //* Do something useful after the post was updated

  //* If the post was updated, remove save_post action
  remove_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_264720_save_post', 10, 3 );
}
//* Hypothetical function hooked to save_post
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_264720_save_post', 10, 3 );
function wpse_264720_save_post( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  //* Bail if post was an update
  if( $update ) {
    return;
  }
  //* Do something useful on save_post
}
```

Comment: I did look into `post_updated`. How can I prevent the initial save-function from fireing through the `save_hook`?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you saying you have another function hooked to save_post? If so, you can use the post_updated callback to remove the save_post action. Or you can use the $update parameter in the save_post function to bail if the post is an update. Both are now shown in the answer.

Comment: Yes. I have another function in the `save_post`-hook to initially save the taxonomy. Now I need to update and delete the taxonomy so that the old ones are not left in the taxonomy. That is where `update_post` comes in. `$update` is useless because it is always true. I guess because of the initial draft. That is why the `update_post`-hook always gets fires. Even when saving an initial post.